# How to get the every week by google spread sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I want to have date of every weeks.

I put `07/02/2022` in `F5` cell and put =EDATE(F5 + 7) in G5 cell

But `N/A` comes in `G5`

I guess maybe I put 07/02/2022 in F5 in a wrong way..

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. read the error message:

Wrong number of arguments to EDATE. Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 arguments.

2. correct G5 to =EDATE(F5,7)

In case you refer to tomorrow's date, that is 2/7/2022.
You are, if you read the help, adding 7 months with the command above.

Answer (score 0):

#### The date of the next week starting on any day

```
function nextWeekDateStartingOnThis(day = 1) {//Sun(0) - Sat(6)
  let dt = new Date();
  let nd = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + 7 - dt.getDay() + day);
  Logger.log(nd);
  return nd;//this returns the date of the next monday because day = 1
}
```

If you want the date of the next tuesday then make day = 2